# How to load next / previous post

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a website where I refer to all my discovering all over the web, has a blog, it refers to several articles but short and one per page.
I'm looking for a function I should put in a `div` to get the previous or next article.
Each line of my SQL array have an `'id'`, `'title'`, `'content'`, `'link'` and `'date'` information.
So, when arriving on the website, we see the last article (as the highest `id`) and I'd like to have a button (prefering to me an editable `div` as a radio button) to get the one less `id` to set new `'id'`, `'title'`, `'content'`, `'link'` and `'date'` on respective `div`'s.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Today I</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
 //On se connecte au serveur
$base = mysql_connect ('dododo.dobido', 'dodobi', 'bibido');
 //On sélectionne la db
mysql_select_db ('do', $base) ;

 //On sélectionne tous les éléments de la table ckga_main, on les trie par ordre décroissant et on sélectionne le premier de la liste (donc l'id le plus élevé)
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM CKGA_main ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';
$req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL !<br />'.$sql.'<br />'.mysql_error());

 //Début de la boucle (TANT qu'il y a des éléments dans ma requête, je sors des $data)
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($req))
{
  ?>

  <div id="ajd">Aujourd'hui j'ai</div>
  <div id="title"><?php echo $data['title']; ?></div>
  <div id="content">
    <?php echo '<a href="'.$data['link'].'">'.$data['content'].'</a>';?>
      </div>
    <?php
} // Fin de la boucle 
mysql_close ();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

You can atually see the result at [this page (I'm french)](http://chezleyoule.com/testbdd/).
So, we can imagine a `<div id="prev_button">Previous Article</div>` who changes all div's content to the new array line.
I looked this function for two days...
I don't know if I have to do a PHP, MySQL, Javascript or jQuery function...
And, I don't even know what look it has to have.

Comment: What is your question? You want a `div` that looks like a `radiobutton` and acts like an `a` tag? Anyway... you are going to have to change your SQL query with a parameter and your `div`/`radiobutton`/`a`-tag will have a link that correspondents with that parameter in the SQL query.

Comment: Medo42 has understood my problem, his solution doesn't really work, but he has catched the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution will have to use the HTML, PHP and SQL level, Javascript is not required.

Let's go through this step by step with a very basic solution. Warning: I haven't done PHP in a while and I'm not checking my code. The solution is also REALLY limited, e.g. I don't check if a previous or next article exists. This is just meant to point you into the right direction.

You want the user to click on something to get new content (the previous article). The most easy way to do this is to use a link which contains the necessary information in the URL - probably the ID of the previous article. Here is what that might look like (inside your while-loop):

`<a href="http://chezleyoule.com/testbdd/?article=<?php echo ($data['id'] - 1); ?>`

The `article=123`-part is a GET parameter. Your script can check if that parameter is there - if it is not, just display the latest page as you do now, but if it is there then use that to fetch the article from your database:

`$sql = 'SELECT * FROM CKGA_main where id=' . intval($_GET['article']);`

Then perform the query and display the article as usual.

Comment: That exactly what my problem is, but that don't even work, the page adress stay at id as 3 http://chezleyoule.com/testbdd/. But it has been a greatful help !

Comment: I can't really start figuring out why it doesn't work without seeing your updated code.

Comment: However, I did make one awful mistake and gave you code that is vulnerable to SQL injection. This is not what causes your problem, but I'll fix it for my peace of mind. Later on, you will want to use parametrized queries to prevent this kind of security issue completely, but I didn't bother because it's not really part of your question...

Comment: And sorry for writing so many comments, but I actually noticed that I used the wrong operator for string concatenation (as I said, PHP, long ago...) I changed it now, so please have another look.

Comment: It's working now ! I just have to redirect my user to the last id page (cause with just the page name nothing is show).

Answer (score 0):

What about a solution of this form:

```
//select all of the post ID's and put them in an array

//pick which post you wish to display (the highest ID if $_GET['postid'] is not set)

//create a button to link to 'mypage.php?postid=<previous_post_id>' if there is one

//create a button to link to 'mypage.php?postid=<next_post_id>' if there is one

//get data from table for current page postid (or $_GET['postid'] if it is set) and display
```

The solution would be very similar if using AJAX, except you wouldn't link to a different page, but rather just update the content and buttons based on the AJAX return

Comment: I'd really like to use AJAX but even I can't masterize or less really understand relationship between PHP and MySQL, I prefer keep on these. But, I'm really sure, if I knew those really good, I'd get it on AJAX.